# expressjs restarting while pushing some value to lowdb

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise, callback

i have tried to push an data to **lowdb.write()** function, here is my code look like:

```
new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
  for (var i = 0; i < accepted_file.length; i++) {
    photo_data[i].mv(`./views/images-gallery/${album_name}/${photo_data[i].name.replace(/\s/g,"-")}`, function(err) {
        if (err) { reject(err) }
    })
  }
  resolve("All Photo Uploaded Successfully!")
}).then((value) => {
  for (var i = 0; i < accepted_file.length; i++) {
    dataPhotoDB.get('photo_data[0].photos').push({
      number: "1",
      photo_name: "",
      original_file_name: accepted_file[i].replace(/\s/g,"-"),
      time_per_photo: ""
    }).write();
  }
  return value
}).catch((error) => {
  console.log(error);
})
```

The code is absolutely working, but the main problem is when i try to run the code, the block **.then** is keep performing to **restarting the server**, because of **lowdb.write()** function. I don't want this problem is happening. It causing the client side is receiving an response as below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXltk.png)

I don't know why to solve this problem, some body please explain to me why it happen :'))

Comment: @JaromandaX ok wait, let me try and changing the code..

Comment: @JaromandaX Well, i have fixing my recent code. The code look like above (**edited code**). The code is still performing restart, due to lowdb.write() function. I have try to delete loop statement and it's still performing the restart.

Comment: @JaromandaX I mean, after the `photo_data[i].mv` is succesfully executed, i need to push the array data through the `dataPhotoDB.get.....write()` / `lowdb.write()` function. Sorry to make you feel lil bit confuse, but that is my case.

Comment: @JaromandaX then i have to know what the correct code is meant, based on my above code :D
with all humility, I ask for your help, please write the correct code :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Solved**]

Library:
- Nodemon

The problem is appear when i try to pushing some array values into the `lowdb` file. Of course it causing **the server is restarting**, because I'm using **nodemon** for my developing purpose and Nodemon is always watching every changing file, and then Nodemon is restarting the server.